# Branes wrapping curves in M-theory. What does it mean?

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, topology, branes

1. What does it mean that a M5-branes wraps a holomorphic curve in M-theory? In specific a lot of Vafa's paper involve various branes (not only M5) wrapping some cycles.
2. What does this really mean intuitively and physically?
3. Also, when a brane intersects a compact divisor in a (non-compact) CY3-fold what does it physically mean?

Comment: @SurgicalCommander maybe you could help with this? :)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103520/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166423/2451

Comment: I am really interested in understanding the above in the context of M-theory because of the more geometrical intuition.

Comment: Hard to tell if the question is after the basic concept or some subtleties of it. Let's first check if the basic concept is clear: a brane configuration of shape some manifold Σ inside a target spacetime X is a suitbaly well behaved map Σ→X. One says that such a configuration wraps cycles in X if it represents the corresponding element in the homology group of X. For instance if Σ=T^2and X=Y×T^2 then the brane wraps that torus surface if the embedding map is the identity onto that torus over some point of Y.

Comment: @UrsSchreiber Would you be able to provide me for some reference? Both from a mathematical point of view as well as a physical one. (Sorry for my -very- late response/